# why Tortoise SVN removes files by "SVN update.."

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am going to use TortoiseSVN and trying to learn it! But I faced an ambiguity in version control action.
I create a test project, and commit it to the repository then I remove some files and folder and again commit the change to the repository. Now I want to retrieve those deleted files and folders through the previous version! ( I think it should be feasible !) so I right clicked on the folder and chose the “Update to reversion...” and used the first version (which contains the deleted items) and chose “copy to working..” so all files got back to their places so far so good but when I tried to commit it does not show anything and when I click on “SVN Update..” , Tortoise removed all the deleted files agian!
In order to test I re-update to the older version and I added a new folder and commit it to SVN, but when I clicked on “SVN update ..” again all of my files were deleted (except the new folder)!
I don’t understand what is the whole point of “update to revision..” when you can’t keep the changes? What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

That's what update does. It updates to the latest version.

Let's clarify this by example. Let's imagine you have the following revisions:

```
1: a.txt b.txt c.txt
2: b.txt (deleted a/c)
```

When you "update to version 1", you will get a-c.txt.

Then, when you say "SVN Update," SVN looks at the tree and says "the latest version is 2; let me delete a.txt and c.txt."

I think what you want is to perform a *rollback* and "undo" checking in the deletion changes. Either that, or just re-add the files and things will work as you expect.

Comment: OK, thanks. But then what is the whole point of “update to revision..” when do I need to use it?! When the changes from this update will always be overridden by the “SVN update...” why they consider that option there?

Comment: @FredJand conceptually, the point is that you want to "temporarily see what the code looked like at revision X." If you want to permanently go back to that version, revert to it, or revert changes from other versions.

Comment: All right, I got confused! When I made a change I can revert before committing, but if I already committed it to the repository then how I can revert it? I mean how I can revert to a previous version?

Comment: It's called "rollback" in SVN parlance. Say you commited revision 37 which you don't like; you can: 1) roll back version to version 36, 2) update to revision 36 and re-commit, 3) roll-back (via reverse merge) changes from revision 36. They're all pretty much equivalent. Let me know if you need specific help.

Comment: Yes I do want to rollback but I don’t how I can do it in Tortoise? 1) where is this “roll back” I can’t find it in the context menu. 2) I did update to older version but I could commit it! How I can do that? (I know that I can hijack those files and copy the high jacked ones and re-commit them! 3) how I can do this one, where is this reverse merge (or what is the steps to do that)?

Comment: @FredJand from TortoiseSVN, right-click, choose Show Log; then right-click a version and pick "revert to this revision" or "revert changes from this revision."

Comment: @FredJand - In other VC systems that support branching better (such as Mercurial and Git), updating to an earlier revision is used to branch from a particular point in time (say, to fix a bug where it was introduced). If you tend to work in a branched fashion, (ie. with multiple things going on at once), you may want to learn Mercurial instead (or in addition).